# Lines on Object

Tags: edges

I have used the Boolean modifier on the object pictured below. I then went into edit mode and linked some vertices, by selecting the vertices and pressing "F". I have done this because the modifier created ngons and I want quads.

Since doing this, the lines that I created are visible in object mode and when rendered. I'm wondering why this is. I understand this to mean I have created something invalid, but it looks fine to me

Any assistance greatly appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out where I went wrong. I was selecting only two vertices when pressing "F", 4 are required to make a face or the edge will "float" above the previous face - hence it going weird

I will leave my question up in case anyone else makes my mistake